# Updating Liferay User Lockout

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I've built a portlet that can administrate users in Liferay.

One of the options I'm looking to implement is the ability to Lock and unlock users using the password lockout.

When I try and update the lockout it does nothing, I'm using the following:

```
UserLocalServiceUtil.updateLockoutById(userId, true)
```

This doesn't throw an exception or log a fault, it looks as though everything went well but the database is not updated and the user account is unaffected.

What's going on? Am I missing something? [The JavaDoc is pretty clear](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalServiceUtil.html#updateLockoutById(long,%20boolean)).

*Note: I'm not trying to deactivate the account, only lock out and unlock the user.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the password policy you must specify the "Lockout Enabled" option as enabled otherwise the method will do nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I had re-configured my Liferay installation and hadn't enabled this option!